# Changing the orientation of pdf exports in Redmine

Tags: redmine

Is there a way to change orientation for pdf export of the "Personal statement" time entry report (the url of the page is `our_server/time_entries/report?only_me=true` and the link points to `our_server/time_entries.pdf?only_me=true`)?

It's in landscape right now, but we'd like to have it portrait.

I suppose there is no way to configure this, but a code change would be okay for us, too.

Can someone point me to the lines that control the orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the place where orientation was set in code.

It was in an EasyRedmine extension file, so it may not be the same if you use the "standard" redmine. Although you could also change it in this file (globally, i.e. for every pdf export):

C:\easyredmine_components\Redmine-2.5.1\lib\plugins\rfpdf\lib\tcpdf.rb